# How to manually include jar files that maven update fail to fetch due to firewall restricions

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

After deleting the .m2 folder to start over and after using maven update with the force update option checked, when I try to launch tomcat i get the following error,

```
Publishing failed with multiple errors
Error reading file C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\ca\juliusdavies\not-yet-commons-ssl\0.3.17\not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.17.jar
C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\ca\juliusdavies\not-yet-commons-ssl\0.3.17\not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.17.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
Error reading file C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\opensaml\opensaml\2.6.6\opensaml-2.6.6.jar
C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\opensaml\opensaml\2.6.6\opensaml-2.6.6.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

From which repository could I download safely those jar files and how can I manually include them in the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to download the jar on your local system.
Then use following command to install it:

```
cd <path that includes your .jar file>
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<jarfile.jar> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<jar>
```

The `version`, `groupId`, `artifactId` and `packaging` needs to be same as what they are in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.groupID</groupId>
  <artifactId>your.artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>your.version</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just realized that there isn't a dependency entry in pom.xml for those two jar files. Considering the pom to be correctly configured, what could be the problem?

Comment: @ChristosK. They could be transitive dependencies.

Comment: It worked great for the opensaml, but I can't find a repo for the not-yet-common-ssl for the 0.3.17 version, the mvnrepository.org has up to 0.3.11

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, is there a way to see/log the actual link that maven tries to download a jar from?

Comment: You can use 'mvn clean install -X ' to see debug log in detail.

Comment: For your last question related to dependencies list: in eclipse if you open pom file there is an option to see dependencies tree( under bottom tabs).